# Reading Oracle boolean filed dbms_utility.is_cluster_database in statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sql-function

I'd like to read `boolean` field from Oracle Database (11g), but I'm unable to do so, probably due to Oracle not fully supporting boolean data format.

Field I'm interessted in is `dbms_utility.is_cluster_database`.

Working statement:

```
set serveroutput on;
BEGIN
  IF dbms_utility.is_cluster_database THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('true');
  ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('false');
  END IF;
END;
```

This statement is working fine, however I need it as SQL query, like `SELECT 'someValue' from dual;`

I've tried:

1. `SELECT dbms_utility.is_cluster_database FROM DUAL;` fails with message "ORA-06553: PLS-382: expression is of wrong type"
2. `SELECT CAST(dbms_utility.is_cluster_database AS INT) FROM DUAL;` fails with same message
3. `SELECT sys.diutil.bool_to_int(dbms_utility.is_cluster_database) from DUAL;` fails with same message
4. `SELECT CASE WHEN (dbms_utility.is_cluster_database) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS MY_BOOLEAN_COLUMN FROM DUAL;` fails with message "SQL Error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator"

I'm out of ideas how it can be fixed.

Problem is definitely not related to database access rights (since "dbms_output" solution works). Also, other fields from `dbms_utility` can be read using simple `SELECT dbms_utility.<something> from dual;`, eg. `SELECT dbms_utility.get_endianness FROM DUAL;`

Comment: Can you create a function that calls this function and returns a data type that is available in SQL?  Can you use a different approach (say, doing a count(*) against `v$instance` to see if there are multiple instances)?

Comment: @JustinCave I cannot create named function on this database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess it's not possible to read boolean values in SQL, but you can write a wrapper function which would analyze that boolean and return varchar2/int/number.

alternatively, in your particular case you can do:

```
select value from v$parameter where name='cluster_database';
```

Comment: Don't guess, it really is not possible. `boolean` data type does not exist in Oracle's SQL context.

Comment: @MaxU thanks, alternative solution you wrote is perfect for me! :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggest @MaxU you can create wrapper function.

```
create or replace function is_cluster_database return number is
begin
  return sys.diutil.bool_to_int(dbms_utility.is_cluster_database);
end is_cluster_database;
```

And then used it like this

```
select is_cluster_database from dual;
```

Of course, result be **number** type.

```
is_cluster_database

0
```

Comment: It's working, but alternative solution proposed by @MaxU is far more easier in this case :)